# What is the need of .trigger("Change ") in this code

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, eventtrigger

```
$("#pass").val("").trigger("change");
$("#pass_con").val("").trigger("change");
```

What  s the use of using trigger statement here

Answer (score 0):

On change event occurs when user enters values manually, i.e. events initiated by user and not the JS code. Setting the value using `.val()` do not trigger change event.

Thus,`.trigger("change");` or `.change();` needs to be used for triggering change event attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

May be there are change listeners registered on `#pass`, `#pass_con` elements.

Changing the value of these nodes programatically will not trigger a change event.

Manually triggering the change event for the listeners to be notified.